# wordpress select first child page only?

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

I have this content structure on wordpress:

```
-father
--child
---grandchild
```

and to get the `child` content i use this:

```
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');
```

the problem with this is that also gets me the content for `grandchild`;
I tried to `$pages[0];` just for fun but as we all know this only got me the first child from all..

also i found  this info of [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) which was the one that come more close to give a clue in how to fix this...

any idea or solution will be really appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but this should work:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=1&post_parent=$post->ID'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

add `&parent='.$post->ID`

```
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc&parent='.$post->ID);
```